# Sqoop - Error while exporting from hive to mysql

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have a problem using sqoop to export hive bigint data to mysql.

The type of the column in mysql and hive is bigint.

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3465195470"
...
At java.lang.Integer.parseInt (Integer.java:583)
```

It seems that an error occurs when converting a string stored in hdfs to a numeric type.

Both hive and mysql columns are bigint types, how do i solve the problem?

add sqoop command

```
export -connect "jdbc:mysql://{url}/{db}?{option}" 
--username {username} 
--password {password} 
--table {username} 
--columns  "column1,column2,column3"  
--export-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/tmp.db/{table} 
--update-mode allowinsert 
--update-key column1 
--input-fields-terminated-by "\001"   
--input-null-string "\\N"  
--input-null-non-string "\\N" 
--null-string "\\N"  
--null-non-string "\\N"
```

Comment: plese share sqoop export command

Comment: Use String Type

Comment: Unfortunately, the type of the mysql column is already bigint.

Comment: Show us the Command please?

Comment: I added the sqoop command to the article.

Comment: Please see this link : https://dzone.com/articles/sqoop-import-data-from-mysql-to-hive

Comment: you sure about column positions? Can you share schema of hive and mysql table. Also there is no need of `--null-string`  and `-null-non-string`

Comment: I saw your opinion and confirmed it. I have confirmed that one column is missing in the hive. I will adopt if you answer. Thank you.

Comment: I wrote an answer on the basis of this. If you have time, you can write better answer for the community. Then I will delete this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be an issue due to missing column or wrong column position.

Also there is no need of `--null-string` and `-null-non-string`. These are used in `sqoop import` commands.